# How can I use Sum() in Linq?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

How do I convert this statement into LINQ?

```
SELECT Sum(Balance) FROM account WHERE name='stocks' AND userid=290;
```

Comment: And what attempt have you made yourself, so far? What piece of code are you having trouble with?

Comment: Similar to your first question, the same topic, the same (poor) quality..

Comment: Thanks for your (poor) info.... @Michal Klouda

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
decimal sumLineTotal = (from od in account
                        where name == 'stocks' && userid == 290
                        select Balance).Sum();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var sum = db.account.Where(a => a.name == "stocks" && a.userid == 290)
                    .Sum(a => a.Balance);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
myBalanceSum = account.Where(x => x.name == 'stocks' && x.userid == 290 ).Sum(x => x.Balance);
```